# Eidolons and Teamwork Feats

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, animal-companions, helping

I'm building a mounted summoner (eidolon is mount) and I'm looking to maximize mounted combat. One way of doing this is with teamwork feats. However, the effectiveness of such a strategy hinges on the "Pack Flanking" feat; which no companion creature is able to qualify for.

I only see two ways around it.

**Option 1.** 
You could grab an item that grants your mount a copy of your teamwork feats. But they are expensive for low level characters:
 - Horsemaster's saddle (12,000 gp)
 - Sky marine's elite saddle (14,000 gp)

**Question 1.** 
Teamwork would come into play in this build at level 7. I haven't played PF past level 3. Would I have enough money to buy one of these without breaking the bank?

**Option 2.**
Or by taking a class that grants 'tactics', such as the hunter. But this will leave me majorly under powered since I am already taking a level in Dragoon (fighter archetype) for 2 mount feats.

However, if Eidolons are considered animal companions then that disadvantage is virtually eliminated. As the AC levels with stack with Eidolon levels. I doubt this is the case but I'm holding out hope.

**Question 2.**
Can Eidolon and Animal Companion Levels Stack?

Edit:
The reason I want Pack Flanking is because it gives me access to feats like:

Harrying Partners
Paired Opportunists
Precise Strike
Out Flank

Which would stack up and become devastating. The characters will also be in the same square as one of them is a mount.

Answer (score 1):

The approximate assumed [wealth by level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering#Table-Character-Wealth-by-Level) for a seventh level character is 23,500 gp, so you could afford such an item but it would account for half your wealth.  Of course, specific campaigns vary, and if you have a party crafter you can halve the cost to you. And youe WBL about doubles every two levels so probably by level 9 it's more affordable, if it's a major part of your build.

No, eidolon levels do not stack in any way with animal companion levels.

An eidolon is not an animal companion so cannot benefit from [Pack Flanking](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/pack-flanking-teamwork) in any event.

However, I suspect you should probably be asking instead what your actual problem is - unless one or both of you have a lot of rogue levels, there's perhaps other better ways to reap a +2 to hit on your opponent, you have mentioned no real reason that you need flanking specifically. For flanking you could possibly use [Gang Up](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/gang-up-combat) instead, with another party member or, you know, a summon.